# Unable to collapse all child nodes of ExtJs Tree panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating a tree panel in ExtJs which further have parent child nodes in it. But I am facing following 2 issues.

1. When I am sending the whole data(all TreeStore data for TreePanel)
   from backend with all childs expanded(by setting *expanded* field to true), it is not able to load all the fields and few fields from top gets removed from the store.

```
                            "id" => <field_id>,
                            "text" => <field_name>,
                            'checked'=> false,
                            'disabled' => false,
                            'expanded' => true,
                            'leaf'=> true,
                            'level'=> 2,
                        ];
```

2. When I try to collapse a parent node having 85 or more fields, not all
   the child nodes gets collapsed. This works fine for less number of data but causing issue if we have large set of child nodes

[image: As you can see parent of Battery Type is missing. Also not all child nodes of parent node - Allergy Advice are collapsed]
As you can see parent of *Battery Type* is missing. Also not all child nodes of parent node - *Allergy Advice* are collapsed

Comment: Please, provide fiddle sample.

Comment: Hi @ArthurRubens
Sorry for the delayed reply. Here is the link to the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3cur&view/editor) 
On collapsing Allergy Advice child system got stuck.

Comment: Strange bug.. The only thing I have found in your tree is duplicated ids: 166, 173, 201, 196, 144, 178, 192.. But I am not sure if that is the reason.

Comment: While running this fiddle example on chrome, it says _Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded_ (in console)